# how can i fix this error: ParseError at [row,col]:[21,35]

Tags: android, xml

Error:

ParseError at [row,col]:[21,35] Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?TextView&app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf&app

AndroidManifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SwitchStuff">
    <activity android:name=".Login">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

build.gradle File:

```
plugins { id 'com.android.application' }

android { compileSdkVersion 30 buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mkrsudios.switchstuff"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.github.VishnuSivadasVS:Advanced-HttpURLConnection:1.2'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I do not know where this error may be but through my research is in any of these files

Comment: See following : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.  The error is in the xml file.  Looks like a namespace issue "Android".  So error seems to be in the file you have "Android" but missing the namespace definition like in link : <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: The error is not in these files. It is in one of your layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `category` and `action` tags are meant to be inside an `intent-filter` tag not a direct child of your `activity` tag:

So replace:

```
<activity android:name=".Login">
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</activity>
```

with:

```
<activity android:name=".Login">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You also need to update your answer with the faulty layout xml file where the `ParseError` is happening, to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using databinding, then make sure that the layout does not have extra fields.

Like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="26dp">
```

this prop throw ParseError:

```
android:layout_height="26dp"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).